# Ignite cache via spring. Dynamic eviction period duration

Tags: java, spring, caching, duration, ignite

I've used `Ignite` cache. It seems work fine via spring.

**Issue 1:** if server restarts cache loses data and does not repairs.

**Solution for issue 1:** use db to persist all cached data.

**Issue 2:** eviction period for each element loaded from db should be different.

*Solution for issue 2: configure cache eviction period duration for each element???*

Following ignite documentation I can configure eviction period for cache as general

```
igniteCacheConfig.setExpiryPolicyFactory(new ExpiryPolicyFactory(duration));
```

but I do not find how to configure it for each element in separate way.

### Question

I need help in my *solution for issue 2* or if it necessary I ready to consider change **Solution for issue 1:** if it helps to get better way with *solution for issue 2*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cache.withExpiryPolicy()](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#withExpiryPolicy(javax.cache.expiry.ExpiryPolicy)) to gain
cache wrapper with specific ExpiryPolicy.
This policy will be used during operations on this cache wrapper, only.

```
IgniteCache<Object, Object> cache = cache.withExpiryPolicy(new
CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5)));
```

You can create as much wrappers as you need and put/get/etc entries using
them.

Here is some [example](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Can-I-set-an-expiry-policy-for-some-specify-entry-td2106.html) described on ignite user list

Comment: how does cache configuration helps solve the issue `eviction period for each element loaded from db should be different` ?

Comment: How you are loading data from db to cache? You can load entries by parts, dynamically changing expiry policy with withExpiryPolicy() method.